# Entity Framework DbContext Update Fails if No Change in Field Values

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

When we pass our DbContext an object whose values have not changed, and try to perform an `Update` we get a `500 internal server error`.

A user may open a dialog box to edit a record, change a value, change it back and then send the record to the database. Also we provide a Backup and Restore function and when the records are restored, some of them will not have changed since the backup was performed.

I was under the impression that a `PUT` would delete and re-create the record so I didn't feel there would be a problem.

For example, having checked that the `Activity` exists my `ActivityController` is as follows:

```
                var activityEntityFromRepo = _activityRepository.GetActivity(id);

            // Map(source object (Dto), destination object (Entity))
            _mapper.Map(activityForUpdateDto, activityEntityFromRepo);

            _activityRepository.UpdateActivity(activityEntityFromRepo);

            // Save the updated Activity entity, added to the DbContext, to the SQL database.
            if (await _activityRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                var activityFromRepo = _activityRepository.GetActivity(id);
                if (activityFromRepo == null)
                {
                    return NotFound("Updated Activity could not be found");
                }

                var activity = _mapper.Map<ActivityDto>(activityFromRepo);
                return Ok(activity);
            }
            else
            {
                // The save failed.
                var message = $"Could not update Activity {id} in the database.";
                _logger.LogWarning(message);
                throw new Exception(message);
            };
```

My `ActivityRepository` is as follows:

```
        public void UpdateActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        _context.Activities.Update(activity);
    }
```

If any of the fields have changed then we don't get the error. Do I have to check every record for equality before the `PUT`? It seems unnecessary.

Perhaps I have missed something obvious. Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: What is the exact exception message you are receiving from EF?

Comment: `PUT http://localhost:5000/api/initialDeviceLocationsCollection 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: This are not the exception details. Please provide correct exception details instead of just front end message which you are getting

Comment: My mistake. I have caught the exception: `{System.Exception: Could not update Campaign ef221ddc-0fe6-4c4a-a2f1-32d2e1fe9593 in the database.
   at GasCircPlanning.Controllers.api.CampaignsController.<UpdateCampaign>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Workspaces\GasCircPlanning\GasCircPlanning\Controllers\api\CampaignsController.cs:line 309}` This is the `CampaignController` but I have the same problem on all controllers.

Comment: If I make a change to any field the `PUT` works fine and returns the updated item. If I call it with everything the same I get an error.

Comment: the execption seems related to `UpdateCampaign`, not to the activity. Could you edit your post with the full exception, innerException, and the stack trace ?

Comment: `The property 'Id' on entity type 'Task' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetPropertyModified(IProperty property, Boolean changeState, Boolean isModified, Boolean isConceptualNull) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry entry)`

Comment: The above was for updating a `Task` object, but it is the same error for `Activity` objects as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of code missing here.

In your code you call your `SaveChangesAsync` (not the EF SaveChangesAsync).
Probably (but there is not the code to be sure) your SaveChangesAsync is something that returns false if there is an exception (and is not a good pattern because you "loose" the exception info) or if `DbSet.SaveChangesAsync` returns 0.
I think (but there is a lot of missing code) that this is your case. If you don't make any changes, `SaveChangesAsync` returns 0.

**EDIT**
The `System.Exception` is raised by your code (last line). EF never throws `System.Exception`.

Comment: Very interesting. My `SaveChangesAsync` method in my repository is like this: `public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0;
        }`

Comment: The issue is your SaveChangesAsync. If the properties does not change it returns false.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. That code was written a while ago and I now see where I went wrong. I will look for a good example implementation to study. Thank you.